# how to get child key from parent key of a node on firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to check if a date does exists on my db.
[image]

lets say my date is 2018-04-23 and then i wanted to check if the date existed on my database so i use this

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val().key); // but this returns undefined. 
        console.log(body.datebook);

})
```

i dont want to use forEach loop for a specific reason. is there a way to get the dates only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val().key); // but this returns undefined. 
    console.log(body.datebook);

})
```

into this:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.key); 
    console.log(body.datebook);

})
```

`key` is a property of `snapshot`. Also it will return the source location.

So if you want it to return the date, then `ref` should be referring to that specific date.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid=user.uid;
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(uid).child("availability").child("2018-04-23");
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: the thing is 2018-04-23 does not exists on my database. is there a way to return a message where this date does not exist on my database?. because when i tried to use `ref` that is referring to a specific date the return from my console was 2018-04-23.

Comment: try to check if it exists like this `if (snapshot.exists()) {
console.log('exist');
}else{
console.log('not exist');
  }`

Comment: this is what im looking for.. .exists() i tried this earlier but it gives me an error so i didn't try it again i thought that .exists can't be used but i didn't notice that i made a typo.. thanks